# Cannot re-call BeginGetRequestStream/BeginGetResponse while a previous call is still in progress

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I am calling httpwebresponse inside the the Task factory and after 1 execution it throws exception
`Cannot re-call BeginGetRequestStream/BeginGetResponse while a previous call is still in progress`
My code is like below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < tsk.Length; i++) 
{ 
   tsk[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew((object obj) => 
   { 
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        watch.Stop(); 
   }, i);
}
```

How to fix this issue

Comment: You should fix your code snippet for us to be able to see what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong formatting , the correct code is :  for (int i = 0; i < tsk.Length; i++)
            {
                


                tsk[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew((object obj) =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.

                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            
           
            watch.Stop();

           



                },
                                        i);

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Because your code isn't making too much sense.

Comment: I have to stress test my server by making parallel call for get method using task factory to spawn multiple parallel threads. But after 1st execution the exception is thrown " Cannot re-call BeginGetRequestStream/BeginGetResponse while a previous call is still in progress"

Comment: I had this problem with WebClient, I saw that I am download a file with url starting with "//". That's fine for browsers, but not with WebClient. So, I added a "http:" to start of the text, then problem solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the same `HttpRequest` object again and again:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

You have to re-create it each time as the separate threads trying to re-use `HTTP` connection concurrently and getting the exception:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I was doing it because my need was to set the request properties at one common place which is common for all threads

Comment: then create a fabric method to reuse this parameters. You still have to create as many instances as you threads count is.

Comment: @VMAtm Can you please elaborate on "create a fabric method to reuse this parameters"

Comment: @saadasharif Create some static helper method with some rules which must be applied to all the requests. Read some literature about Design Patterns